# Problem filtering Array in Array by date between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I'm just using a method to filter it's working like a charm but I'm losing my original Array when there is no date between I provided (as expected). What can I do to not lose my Array.

I want this because when a person gives a new date, filter it without a reload. But I cannot do it with empty Array..

Here is my function;

```
filterByDate(d) {
  this.orders = this.orders.filter(
    (element) =>
      element.order.orderdate >= d[0] &&
      element.order.orderdate <= d[1]
  );
},
```

d[0] is fromDate, d[1] is toDate. Thanks.

Comment: filter() method creates a new array instead of changing original. Have you tried to remove items from original array without using filter() method.

Comment: No I didn't but I just don't want to touch my original Array, either way I will need to force re-render or reload the page to get original Array from api. Maybe there is a Vue way of doing this, I'm pretty new to Vue!

I've just saved my Array to store and added a button to reset it's set's my original array from store, it is solving my problem actually. But If there is a better way I'm waiting for it!

Comment: Why don't you use original array from store in ```filterByDate(d)```. I mean like this, ```this.orders = this.originalOrders.filter()```. Vuex has ```mapState``` to make this easier.

Comment: Brilliant! Never think about that. This solves my problem thanks a lot!

Comment: :) You are welcome! Can you please update your post with these information because then it is easier to understand this for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment section of problem,

- filter() method doesn't modify the original array. instead, it creates a new one.
- `this.orders = this.orders.filter()` will be caused to lose original array. Therefore, you need to store it in different variable before. (Ex: `this.originalOrders`)
- Then `this.originalOrders` can be used for filtering,

```js
filterByDate(d) {
  this.orders = this.originalOrders.filter(
    (element) =>
      element.order.orderdate >= d[0] &&
      element.order.orderdate <= d[1]
  );
},
```

Thanks!